# How to get file extension from SwiftAttachment object in Laravel Email Transport

Tags: laravel

This is Laravel 8. I'm extending Illuminate\Mail\Transport\Transport class to create a custom mail transport in order to utilize the company's custom mail API with Illuminate\Mail\Mailable. I got most of it working, including file attachments, however the Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity and the classes deriving from it contain getBody(), getFilename(), getSize(), and getContentType() but no methods to extract file extension.

```
<?php

namespace App\CustomMailDriver;

use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use Illuminate\Mail\Transport\Transport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage;

class CustomTransport extends Transport
{
    /**
     * Guzzle client instance.
     *
     * @var \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * API key.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $key;

    /**
     * The API URL to which to POST emails.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * Create a new Custom transport instance.
     *
     * @param  \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface  $client
     * @param  string|null  $url
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client, string $url, string $key)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function send(Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage $message, &$failedRecipients = null)
    {
        $this->beforeSendPerformed($message);

        $payload = $this->getPayload($message);
        
        try {
            // ignore ssl (esp when working in DEV/QA)
            $response = Http::withoutVerifying()->withHeaders([
                'X-Authorization' => $this->key 
            ])->post($this->url, $payload);
            Log::info($response->body());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->sendPerformed($message);

        return $this->numberOfRecipients($message);
    }

    /**
     * Get the HTTP payload for sending the message.
     *
     * @param  \Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage  $message
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getPayload(Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage $message): array
    {
        // to
        if (!empty($message->getTo())) {
            $payload['payload']['to']['email'] = key($message->getTo());
        }
        // cc
        if (!empty($message->getCc())) {
            $payload['payload']['cc']['email'] = key($message->getCc());
        }
        // bcc
        if (!empty($message->getBcc())) {
            $payload['payload']['bcc']['email'] = key($message->getBcc());
        }
        // subject
        $payload['payload']['subject'] = $message->getSubject();

        // html
        $payload['payload']['message']['html'] = $message->getBody();

        // message children contains plain text, attachments, etc
        $children = $message->getChildren();

        if (!empty($children)) {

            foreach($children as $child) {

                // attachments
                if (get_class($child) === 'Swift_Attachment') {

                    $payload['payload']['attachments'][] = [
                        'content' => base64_encode($child->getBody()),
                        'filename' => $child->getFilename(),
                    ];
                }
                // plain text
                if (get_class($child) === 'Swift_MimePart') {
                    $payload['payload']['message']['text'] = $child->getBody();
                }
            }
        }

        return $payload;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to go different route. Instead of searching the extension inside Transport class using Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage, I passed the filename with the original extension to Transport class from Illuminate\Mail\Mailable

```
public function build()
    {
        $tempUpload = request()->file('file_attachment');
        $filename = $tampUpload->getClientOriginalName() . "." . $tempUpload->getClientOriginalExtension();

        return $this->from($this->from_email, $this->from_name)
            ->subject('subject line')
            ->attach($tempUpload, ['as' => $filename)
            ->view('emails.gce.supplier_supplier')
            ->with($this->data);
    }
```